# How to create pages from markdown in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm in the process of migrating my blog from Sapper to SvelteKit. I've written blog posts using markdown, and I was using [markedjs](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) to import the markdown files and export them to my component. It looks like this approach doesn't work with SvelteKit, however.

How would I do this using SvelteKit? Do I need a Vite plugin?

Comment: This is magic: https://mdsvex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`npx svelte-add mdsvex` from: [svelte-add/msvex](https://github.com/svelte-add/mdsvex) did the heavy lifting for me.